# Android Install android support rev.20 on SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

in eclipse my project need to install `Android Support Library, revision 20`. i don't have that on android SDK to install.

[image: Android SDK]

in Eclipse after choose android support library i get this error and could not download it.

```
[2014-08-14 13:04:02 - SDK Manager]   Download finished with wrong size. Expected 5506557 bytes, got 0 bytes.
[2014-08-14 13:04:02 - SDK Manager] Done. Nothing was installed.
```

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if google is Filtered your country you can use any software to change ip and download it